# Wordpress image permissions issue

Tags: php, wordpress, image, upload, file-permissions

I developed a site two years ago in Wordpress that the client uploads images for displaying, but suddenly as of 2014 the images don't show up any more.  When you upload them you get a broken image icon on the upload media page and in the website.  The first thing I checked was the permissions on the folders, but they are all the same and 2013 and 2012 folders can see the images.  I also checked to make sure the plugin code I wrote didn't accidentally have a hard-coded date, which it didn't so that's not the case either. The uploads/2014/images get this error:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wp-content/uploads/2014/03/hungarian-club-logo-sml-98x100.png on this server.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that the images are uploaded and located in the correct folder with regards to the above url.

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm officially stumped.

Thanks

Comment: did you try chmod 777 in the wordpress folder? (but there is a risk when using this command, better read more about it before using it).or maybe the url has changed.

Comment: Hi Furtano, I'm not sure why, but I tried the permissions again and it worked.  So I set Wordpress' upload folder to 0777.  Thanks for making me go back and repeat that, otherwise I'd still be here scratching my head.